# Relativization in ZFC

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let N be a set in ZFC.  Let ZFC+ be ZFC with the additional axioms that, whenever phi is a sentence which is an axiom of ZFC, phi relativized to N is an axiom of ZFC+.  Now suppose that the sentence s has a proof in ZFC, can we know that s relativized to N has a proof in ZFC+?  If so, how can we know this, because proofs in ZFC can be very varied and aren't necessarily simple manipulations in the style of propositional logic.  Thank you, Paul Epstein

Comment: All proofs (as far as FOL is concerned) are simple. You have a list of axioms to start with, and a few deduction rules (sometimes just MP, sometimes a few more). So a proof is a sequence of axioms and deductions (well, it's actually a tree, if you want to think about it in a slightly more correct way, but since these are all finite, it doesn't matter all that much).

Comment: Ultimately if you want a totally rigorous proof of this (avoiding semantic methods), you'll need to argue by induction on proof length. This gets tedious, but isn't hard.

Comment: Thanks @AsafKaragila and NoahSchweber  I think I get it now.  I'd appreciate it if someone could either confirm or correct.  ZFC has rules of inference.  It needs to be verified that deductions made using relativizations of the rules of inference remain valid.

Comment: @Paul Yeah, that’s correct. One would also need to check the relativizations of the logical axioms (if there are any) can be proved. (What needs to be done precisely depends heavily on the choice of proof system for first order logic.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we do know that $s$ relativised to $N$ is provable in ZFC$+$.

This is due to the Soundness Theorem.

The proposition $N \models \phi$, where $\phi$ is a sentence, means that $\phi$, with all quantifiers relativised to $N$, is true.

The Soundness Theorem states that if $\phi$ is provable in first-order logic and $N$ is a structure, then $N \models \phi$.

Now let us suppose that $s$ is provable in ZFC. Then we can take particular axioms $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$ of ZFC such that $(\bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n \phi_i) \to s$ is provable in first-order logic.

In particular, then, we have $N \models (\bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n \phi_i) \to s$. This is by definition equivalent to saying that if $N \models \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n \phi_i$, then $N \models s$.

Now we know that for all $i = 1$ to $n$, we have $N \models \phi_i$. That is, we have $\bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n N \models \phi_i$. This is by definition equivalent to $N \models \bigwedge\limits_{i = 1}^n \phi_i$.

Therefore, $N \models s$.

Comment: Oh, I get it now!  So we think of N as being a model for the axioms of ZFC.  That point of view never occurred to me.  Thanks.  @MarkSaving

Comment: @PaulEpstein You're welcome. But keep in mind that you will not actually be able to prove in ZFC+ that $N \models ZFC$. More precisely, for every axiom $\phi$ of ZFC, you can prove $N \models \phi$. But you cannot prove that for all axioms $\phi$, $N \models \phi$. This is a slight subtlety.

Comment: Yes, Weaver explains this very well.  The finiteness of the number of axioms is crucial when proving consistency, and ZFC has an infinite number of axioms.  Maybe, calling (and thinking of N as) a model of ZFC is misleading (or even wrong).  Do you think it's helpful to think of N as modelling the finite list of axioms relevant to the proof that is being discussed?  I think the right viewpoint is crucial, here.

Comment: Actually, I think you might be making the point that formal systems can't use self-reference -- a consequence of the 2nd Incompleteness theorem that systems can't prove their own consistency.  So in the language of ZFC, there's no way of saying "all axioms of ZFC"..  So we have ZFC, then a metalanguage which expresses what can be proved in ZFC, but then potentially, we could have a metametalanguage etc.  This all shows that there's no hope of getting a closed and rigorous fomalization of modern mathematics.

Comment: Weaver's Metatheorem 7.4 is explained in a really confusing way -- no wonder it took me ages to get it.  He points out that, in ZFC+, you can prove a statement relativized to N and the negation of that statement relativized to N.  At that point, he should (in my opinion) point out that N is non-empty (else some of the axioms of ZFC would fail relative to N), and then point out that the proof is now done since we've shown an inconsistency in ZFC+, contradicting the earlier result.  It isn't that the proof "can be converted" into a proof by contradiction -- it already is a proof by contradiction

Comment: @PaulEpstein You are correct that I am referring to the 2nd incompleteness theorem. However, it is perfectly possible to refer within ZFC to the set of all axioms of ZFC. After all, it's pretty easy to describe the required forms of the axioms. I haven't read Weaver so I'm not sure exactly what you're getting at there. Proving the relative consistency of ZFC and ZFC+ is just a matter of proving the reflection principle.

Comment: As a newbie, I think that: If a writer says something like "If phi is an axiom of ZFC then..." then they will generally be working outside of ZFC (depending on how the argument continues).  However, within ZFC, you can construct 0, 1, 2....,  Basically you can create PA.  Then you can identify axioms of ZFC using Goedel coding of natural numbers.  ZFC can refer to itself that way.  The way to see that N⊨ZFC does not hold (as you say) is to observe the proof of the reflection principle to note that the finiteness of the list of axioms being "reflected" is essential.

Comment: I think I can prove (or at least clearly see why) that N⊨ZFC does not hold for any N.  Any ordinal can be shown to exist in ZFC.  So N would have to demonstrate the existence of every ordinal.  This contradicts the fact that the class of all ordinals is not a set.